# MySQL cyclically one row for each valid user

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, cycle

Here's the background, I have a table `object` containing :

- id
- user (id from user table)
- date (date)
- state (0|1)

And another table `user` containing :

- id
- state (0|1)

EX.:

```
Object
    ID  |  USER  |  DATE  |  STATE
    1      1      2012-10-01 1
    2      2      2012-08-01 1
    3      3      2012-10-01 1
    4      3      2012-10-02 1
    5      3      2012-09-01 1
    6      3      2012-10-01 1
    7      1      2012-10-02 1
    8      2      2012-10-02 0
    9      2      2012-10-02 1
    10     1      2012-10-01 1
    11     2      2012-10-01 1
    12     3      2012-10-01 0
    13     4      2012-11-11 1

Users
    ID  |  STATE
    1   |  1
    2   |  1
    3   |  1
    4   |  0
```

I would make a request to display **one object per valid state user cyclically**, if object state is active, order by date DESC.
EX. result :

```
ID  |  USER  |  DATE  |  STATE
10     1      2012-11-01 1
9      2      2012-10-02 1
4      3      2012-10-02 1
7      1      2012-10-02 1
11     2      2012-10-01 1
3      3      2012-10-01 1
1      1      2012-10-01 1
2      2      2012-08-01 1
6      3      2012-10-01 1
5      3      2012-09-01 1
```

I can do simple queries but then I admit to not knowing how to do here.

**EDIT 2012-11-22 :**
Let trying another approch... With this query (thanks Michiel van Vaardegem), I have a list of users, in order that I want... the one with freshness object on top.

```
SELECT o.user
FROM object o
INNER JOIN users ON user.id = o.user
WHERE o.state=1 AND users.state=1
GROUP BY o.user
ORDER BY o.date DESC
```

Result is :

```
USER
1
2
3
```

NEW QUESTION APPROCH :
With this list of ids, the possible calculated count of rows, and user defined vars, do you think something could be done? 
Exemple :

1. Assuming this list, **SELECT * FROM object WHERE user IN
   ($thislist) AND state=1 ORDER BY date DESC**
2. For each object row depending of user (here I don't know how to explain in mysql)
   **incrementing a rank var with the userposition(in cycle) + usercount**
3. **ORDER BY rank LIMIT n,x** that result

I whant to rank my objects in a user cycle, like :

```
object from user 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,etc... if exist
```

Do this new approch algo be realizable in a mysql query, and if possible how... that is the great question?

Can anybody see a solution only in MySQL?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT o.id, o.user, o.date, 1 AS state
FROM object o
INNER JOIN user ON u.id = o.user
WHERE o.state = 1 AND u.state = 1
GROUP BY o.user, o.date
ORDER BY o.user, o.date DESC
```

I'm not sure, but if I read it correctly, you only want records where the state in both tables is '1', correct?
And you want to sort first on user and then on the date desc?

Comment: Yeah correct, but in a cycle client 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,1,1,etc... I'll try your query in few minutes ;) thanks

Comment: Ah my bad, this query returns first all the records for user 1, then for user 2 etc

Comment: If you switch the order by clause, you will have each user per date, but this is still not what you want

Comment: I have tryed too, and not what I whant , arf... there is no way to cycle results assuming on the number of valid users?